# Android studio 2.0 unable to load project correctly - wearable.iml is not well formed

Tags: android, android-studio, wear-os, android-studio-2.0-beta5

Everytime i try and load my project using android studio 2.0 Beta 6 i get the following error:

[image]

After that i sync gradle and im able to work with the project. I tried going to file-->Invalidate Caches /Restart and i invalidated the cache which clears history.  Obviously the error is saying a xml file is not correctly formed but how can i correct this ?

The other thing i notice is that everytime i load the project it starts the wearable app has the default project like this:

[image]
My project structure is simple. Here is the settings.gradle file:

```
    include ':app', ':wearable',':SliderPreference'
project(':SliderPreference').projectDir = new File('libs/AndroidSliderPreference')
```

After i do a gradle sync the project seems fine but when i load the app module as a signed release, the wearable app never loads automatically anymore so i know something wrong. I can load the wearable by itself through a install but a signed app module should automatically install a wearable project but now its no longer working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I got a problem with the .iml files, I do this:

1. I open Android Studio to run the project
2. I delete the .iml which got a problem.
3. I Rebuild the project Build > Rebuild Project.

After that I have no problem.